# Swift protocol conformace

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a class extension:

```
extension UICollectionViewCell {

    class func registerFromNibInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, forReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
    ...
    }

}
```

Some of collection view cells conforms to protocol `UICollectionViewCellsProtocol`. I'd like to create another version of `registerFromNibInCollectionView` (with different method signature) for cells, that conforms to protocol.

I've tried `extension UICollectionViewCell where Self: UICollectionViewCellsProtocol {`, but have no luck. Any ideas how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve that by extending the protocol itself

```
protocol UICollectionViewProtocol {}
extension UICollectionViewProtocol {
    static func registerFromNibInCollectionView (collectionView: UICollectionView, forReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        //code
    }
}

class MyClass:UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewProtocol {

}
MyClass.register... // will work fine
```

Comment: This is not what I really intended to do. With your approach my cell will conform to given protocol. What I'd like to achieve is add function to `UICollectionViewCell` if `UICollectionViewCell` conforms to given protocol.

Formally: if `UICollectionViewCell` confroms to `UICollectionViewProtocol`, then I should have a function

Comment: I misunderstood :) , I've edited the answer. I hope this helps you

Comment: I'm not sure why you used CollectionType. With that approach I'm not able to call `MyCellClass.registerFromNib...`

Comment: Thats because you can use 'where' only on generic type extensions

Comment: I think I finally understand what you're trying to do. check the answer again